# Is emplace always efficient than insert when adding an element into a map?

Tags: dictionary, insert, c++17, emplace

In my thought, `emplace` is always a better option than `insert`, because in some case `emplace` could save one time of ctor and in other cases it could directly replace `insert` with the same invoking form.

But now I have a map and add an element into it with `insert` with initialize_list

```
map<string, map<int,int>> m1;
if (auto it = m1.find("c1"); it == m1.end()){
    m1.insert({ "c1", {{10, 1}} });
}
```

But with `emplace` I could not think of any way that as consice as `insert` and still get the benifits what `emplace` provides.Like below? It would be ill-formed and compiles in error.

```
auto [it, inserted] = m1.try_emplace("c1", 10, 1);
```

So how to `emplace` in my case? And is it true that `emplace` is always better than `insert`?

Comment: You seem to define "better" as "more performant" sometimes, and as "requires less typing" other times. What criterion do you wish to optimize for?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik both better, but more on "more performant"

Comment: I do believe `emplace` always performs the same or better; I can't think of a scenario where `insert` would win. Well, maybe if you copy a key/value pair from one map to another, and thus already have it in the right form for `insert`. To make `emplace` work with your example, you'd have to write `m1.emplace("c1", map<int,int>{{10, 1}});`